What's the movie where a boy suspects his girlfriend to be a hooker but finds out she does phone sex as job?
I saw a Hollywood rom-com where the guy is really into this girl but gradually begins to suspect she's a hooker as she walks out to attend mysterious phone calls during their date and he overhears her moaning and talking about sex on phone. In the end he learns that she works as phone sex worker, not a hooker.
The details are only true to my memory but I hope it's pretty much like that. Can someone please refer the name of the movie?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Could be Valentine's Day "Anne Hathaway and Topher Grace"'s story
and here's the final scene after he found out 




I saw the movie a long time ago (about the time it was released I guess, so 1996), but from the details you wrote it seems to me you might be looking for a Spike Lee movie, Girl 6
Here's the movie trailer
Girl 6
And this is a short synopsis of the movie taken from IMDB:
"This Spike Lee film examines the life of an aspiring actress in New York. She is upset by the treatment of women in the movie industry during one of her screen tests with 'QT'. Out of work and desperate for money, she decides to take a job as a phone-sex operator. Here, unlike her previous dealings with potential employers, her (female) boss is kind, caring, and sensitive. Later, she begins to get too engrossed in her work and starts to lose touch with reality, represented by her friend and neighbor, Jimmy."
